# Copying a specific field from a vector into another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a basket system for a C++ program, and I am stuck with the task of obtaining the price from one vector in a separate class, and copying that price into the new "Basket" Vector. i have tried a number of workaround but I have gotten as far as having it return the error message that the identifier is undefined, even though the vector is public in the class.

the header file :

```
class Item {
private:
    int _ItemNo;
    string _category, _description;
    double _price;
    double _VAT = _price*0.2;
    double _subtotal = _price + _VAT;

};

class ItemMenu {
public:
    vector<Item> _Items;

    ItemMenu();
    void displayMenu();
};

//Class for ordering from the menu
class Ordering {
    private:
            vector<Item> _Basket;
            int quantity;
            double total;
    public:
            Ordering();
            Ordering(int quantity, double total);
            void placeOrder(const vector<Item> &Items);
```

The implementation file:

```
ItemMenu::ItemMenu() {
    ifstream fin("Menu.txt");
            if(fin) {
                    while(!fin.eof()) {
                            string _ItemNoTemp;
                            getline(fin, _ItemNoTemp, ':');
                            int _ItemNo = stoi(_ItemNoTemp);
                            string _category;
                            getline(fin, _category, ':');
                            string _description;
                            getline(fin, _description, ':');
                            string _priceTemp;
                            getline(fin, _priceTemp);
                            double _price = stod(_priceTemp);
                            if(!fin.eof()) {
                            _Items.push_back(Item(_ItemNo,
                            _category, _description, _price));
                            };
                            fin.peek();
                    }
                    fin.close();
                }

}

//Method to display the each item
void ItemMenu::displayMenu() {
    for(int i = 0; i < _Items.size(); ++i) {
            _Items[i].display();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
Ordering::Ordering() {          }

void Ordering::placeOrder() {
    int select;
    cout << "Please enter an item number: ";
    cin >> select;
    Item I;
    i._subtotal = _Items[select]._subtotal;
    _Basket.push_back(i);
}
```

It is in the ordering class that the basket vector is in, and I am trying to get the subtotal for the items, so that I may calculate the total by summing the values in the vector. This is also where the error saying that _Items is undefined appeared. I am new to programing and haven't really been able to find a clear source for how vectors work between classes depending on where they are declared.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
void Ordering::placeOrder(
      const vector<Item>& items ) {
    int select;
    cout << "Please enter an item number: ";
    cin >> select;
     
     cItem i;
     i._price = items[ select ]._price;
    _Basket.push_back( i );
}
```

Comment: Would this not still keep _Items undefined. that's what I don't really understand, if I could get past that understanding then I should be fine.

Comment: Answer modified

Comment: I'm trying this soulution so I'll keep you updated, however in my main file when I create an instance for the class called 'Ordering start;'. and call the function using 'start.placeOrder(const vector<Item> &Items)', I get the error saying that I need an expression at const. I'm just wondering why it isn't able to call and what the correct way looks like

Comment: Do not paraphrase error messages.  Post the exact message ( it has valuable information ) and the code near the line that is generating the error

Comment: ok thanks, but I've also managed to get it working thanks for your help and ill upload the asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually pass an ItemMenu object to this function. That's why you are getting an undefined error.

Instead of this

```
void Ordering::placeOrder() {
    int select;
    cout << "Please enter an item number: ";
    cin >> select;
    _Basket.push_back(_Items[select]._subtotal);
}
```

You would want to do this

```
void Ordering::placeOrder(ItemMenu yourItemMenuVarible) {
    int select;
    cout << "Please enter an item number: ";
    cin >> select;
    _Basket.push_back(_Items[select]._subtotal);
}
```

then when you call it you would pass it the ItemMenu variable you defined and I think that should fix it.

I would also recommend you not have variables like the vector public, it not a very good practice for security reasons. Learning good habits now will help you in the future. The idea of keeping them private is called *Encapsulation* here are some sources on the topic

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/encapsulation-in-c/
- [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_encapsulation.htm#:~:text=Encapsulation%20is%20an%20Object%20Oriented,from%20outside%20interference%20and%20misuse.&text=This%20means%20that%20they%20can,other%20part%20of%20your%20program](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_encapsulation.htm#:%7E:text=Encapsulation%20is%20an%20Object%20Oriented,from%20outside%20interference%20and%20misuse.&text=This%20means%20that%20they%20can,other%20part%20of%20your%20program).

Comment: i have made the changes that you stated, having yourItemMenuVariable being _Items, however now I am receiving a different error message that reads "no operator "[]" matches these operands -- operand types are: ItemMenu [ int ]". Also thanks for the resources, I'll be sure to look them over!

Comment: @CrispyRoti I didn't notice it your code initially, but to access a vector variable use ItemMenu.at(your_index_int) instead of the array [] operators

It would also help to see you're updated code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys i ended up fixing it with your help the code is below.
Header File:

```
class Ordering {
    private:
            vector<Item> _Basket;
            int quantity;
            double total;
    public:
            Ordering();
            Ordering(int quantity, double total);
            void placeOrder(vector<Item> Items);

};
```

Implementation:

```
Ordering::Ordering() {          }

void Ordering::placeOrder(vector<Item> _Items) {
    int select;
    Item i;
    char cont;
    do{
            cout << "Please enter an item number: ";
            cin >> select;
            i._ItemNo = _Items[select-1]._ItemNo;
            i._description = _Items[select-1]._description;
            i._subtotal = _Items[select-1]._subtotal;
            _Basket.push_back(i);
            cout << i._subtotal;
            cout << "Do you want to add another Item? (y/n): ";
            cin >> cont;
    }while(cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');

 for (int i; i < _Basket.size(); i++) {
    cout << _Basket[i]._ItemNo << ':' << _Basket[i]._description 
    << ':' << char(156) << _Basket[i]._subtotal << endl;
};
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Billing Program" << endl <<
     "--------------------------------" << endl;
    Ordering start;
    ItemMenu display;
    display.displayMenu();
    start.placeOrder(display._Items);
}
```

Comment: "void Ordering::placeOrder(vector<Item> _Items) {"  This is bad parctice.  You are causing tan unneccessary vector copy, which at best is innefficient, and also not allowing the compiler to check for modifications to the vector.  Use: const vector<Item>&

Comment: Also, it looks like you have decided to use _ as an indication of a class attribute.  Fine.  But then you name the function parameter _Items which makes tyou code hard to understand and maintain.